# At least what outdoor temperature should I concern about the risk of water in pipes getting frozen?

Tags: water, pipe, freezing

At least what outdoor temperature should I concern about the risk of water in pipes of a house getting frozen? I guess water in pipes of houses won't get frozen in NJ, even houses don't have heat turned on? Thanks.

Comment: Depends a LOT of where they are placed and the amount of insulation between them and the outside walls or basement.  If there is no heat in the house, it seems like it might be a vacation home.  If so, best bet is to winterize the home, IE: turn off the water heater, turn off the water supply, open all the faucets and blow out the pipes with an air compressor.

Comment: Water starts freezing at 32 degrees.  If never below 32 should be safe, but a week at below 32 outside in an unheated house should have worries.

Comment: Good point re draining the system if the property will be unoccupied.

Comment: and you will need a compressor, who has one (not most of us)? and a port to connect air hose, who has one ?

Comment: @crip659 thanks. How long does it take to freeze water in pipes at or below 32? A week?

Comment: Hopefully a week(do not count on that long) for pipes inside of an unheated house.  Outside a couple of hours.  This is for standing/non running water without heat.

Comment: Remember Texas a couple years ago.  A lot of inside water pipes froze, so did a lot of other things.  NJ is much further north than Texas.

Comment: @Ruskes   a small compressor isn't very expensive (think porter cable pancake style) a couple of fittings to an outdoor hose bib and off you go.   If the outdoor hose bib has a check valve, they could also use the cold water supply to the washing machine.     If this is a vacation home, I'm certain they could afford a small compressor.  They cost between $100 and $200 at home depot.   BLow out the pipes, leave all the faucets open, leave the water supply turned off.

Comment: If you open **all** the taps and let the water drain from pipes, it will in most cases be "enough" for the supply pipes. The drain traps & toilets will need some non-toxic antifreeze added.

Comment: Answer to the title is *yes*.

Comment: "I guess water in pipes of houses won't get frozen in NJ" Yes they would. In central NJ we had 5°F and the upstairs bathroom cold water pipe in our fully-lived-in heated house froze. Took a couple hours of trickling the hot water and a space heater suspended pointing at the ceiling below to get the cold water to flow.

Answer (score 3):

Water in pipes can certainly freeze in NJ, if they're cold enough for sufficient time and they aren't flowing (water mains will generally be at ground temperature for the area, or roughly the yearly average, so running water brings a bit of heat up with it) or heated. It will be less common than farther north where cold snaps are more common and longer, but it's not as if you never have a full week below freezing. Even under normal circumstances,  leakage of general house heating may not be sufficient to warm pipes in outside walls. When heat is off, interior pipes are also at risk, and the danger starts at 32 degrees F as others have said, and gets worse as temperature drops and ice expands.

Note that this risk applies to hydronic heating systems too. Old cast-iron pipes and radiators may be strong enough to survive some abuse but I wouldn't like to bet on it. Newer systems with components using thinner metal for better heat transfer are definitely worth worrying about. I've never heard of anyone running antifreeze through these systems, though theoretically that might be possible

Again as others have said: if solid pipes will be left in freezing conditions, they really should be drained, for exactly the same reasons that we drain the pipe leading to an outside tap. If they can't be drained for some reason, leaving a trickle of warmer water running through them is definitely better than nothing.

(Thanks to those who caught my misreading of the question.)

Comment: You want insulation between the pipes(and heated air) and outside walls.  Anything else and asking for it.  For pipes on outside walls should be pipes, then the wall with insulation inside and outside wall.

Comment: There's no heated air in this question.

Comment: @crip659: Absolutely, but with blown-in insulation you don't always get to choose, unless you're willing to make a special effort to shift the pipes or re-plumb afterwards.

Comment: 2 cents: My parents have a two story home in Columbus, OH, with water pipes running in an exterior wall from the basement to the second floor. They are in the single stud wall, so only an inch or so of insulation, then sheathing, then aluminum siding.  Those pipes have never frozen, much to our surprise.

Comment: Heat leakage from inside may have helped protect them, especially if they are inside that 1" insulation.

Comment: Antifreeze in hydronics is seen, but it's also rare since it involves more complexity (no boiler fill valve using water pressure - you have to pump in the antifreeze mix and have a tank for it, etc.) Still, can be highly worthwhile when "things happen" and there's no stress about the system freezing/bursting.

Comment: Makes sense, E. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the house is, as stated, **unheated**

> even houses don't have heat turned on?

then **32°F / 0°C** is really all it takes.

Water supply pipes (outside the house) are normally installed below frost line in freezing climates, but pipes inside a house above that level are certainly at severe risk. It's only a question of how fast the unheated house cools. That varies too much by house to generalize about. The longer it's below freezing and the further below freezing it goes, the more likely it is that pipes will freeze.

A random spot in NJ (since a specific location has not been mentioned) shows a forecast of 29°F for Saturday night and 26°F for Sunday night. The Saturday looks like 2-3 hours below freezing, the Sunday is at least 10 hours. I would not care to bet on the pipes in an **unheated** house not freezing on Sunday. They will certainly freeze in January or February if they somehow make it through December without freezing.

The math changes somewhat if the house *was being heated* and loses heating, since the thermal mass of the house was warmed and needs to cool. If the house starts unheated, you have a lot less time before the inside reaches freezing temperatures.

*If nobody is dealing with the issue, the other thing that will take somewhat longer to freeze, but make an awful mess when they do are the toilets.*

Comment: The house may be normally heated and still freeze pipes in the house.  If the pipes are close to an outside wall with little or no insulation.

Comment: No kidding. The question is about unheated houses, though. Which is a considerably worse scenario if the pipes have not been drained.

Comment: Thanks where do you see the weather forecast?

Comment: The national weather service website.

Comment: How many licks does it take? (you live in climate zone 4 or 5?) FA and you *will* find out, +1.